# Control flow plug in of GeoServer 2.18.2 doesn't show on GeoServer Tools

Tags: geoserver, extensions

I already downloaded and added to Lib folder as all other extensions of GeoServer that I needed but I am having issue loading the control flow extension which I confirmed that it is same version as my GeoServer 2.18.2 (war file version installed on Java 64 bit) .

Comment: what does the log file say?

Comment: Doesn't say anything, i just can't see it on tools so i can configure it, i don't know if there is any way of checking if it is installed or not

Comment: it doesn't show up in the tools, there is a file to edit - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/controlflow/index.html

Comment: But i can't find that file. Should i create it? or the fact that it is not there means that the plug in is not installed or recognize by geoserver?

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you verify your installation:https://www.geocat.net/docs/geoserver-enterprise/2020.5/productionenterprise/controlflow.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).